# "no such column: id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id ..."

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
DataBaseAlarm mDbHelper = new DataBaseAlarm(this);

        db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME+" ("+rowid+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Title+TEXT_TYPE+Time+TEXT_TYPE+Date+TEXT_TYPE+Repeat+TEXT_TYPE+Note+" TEXT NOT NULL);";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

    }
Cursor c = db.query(

                "Alarms",  // The table to query
                cols,      // The columns to return
                null,      // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,      // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,      // don't group the rows
                null,      // don't filter by row groups
                null       // The sort order
        );

from=new String[]{"title","note","time","date","repeat","_id"};
        to=new int[]{R.id.title_row,R.id.note_row,R.id.time_row,R.id.date_row,R.id.repeat_row};

        adapterCursor =new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.alarm_row, c, from, to);

        l_list.setAdapter(adapterCursor);

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("title",msg);

        cv.put("note",note);

        cv.put("time",hour+":"+minute);

        cv.put("date",month+"/"+day+"/"+year);

        cv.put("Repeat","daily");

        db.insert("Alarms",null,cv);
```

and for some reason I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, title, time, date, repeat, note FROM Alarms

Comment: Format your code first

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your table creation code:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME+" ("+rowid+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Title+TEXT_TYPE+Time+TEXT_TYPE+Date+TEXT_TYPE+Repeat+TEXT_TYPE+Note+" TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

It's a mess, and it's full of errors.
It should be something like:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + 
    " (" + rowid + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    Title + " TEXT, " + Time + " TEXT, " + Date + " TEXT, " +
    Repeat + " TEXT, " + Note + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

**[EDIT]**

Also, this

```
cv.put("date",month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
```

is not a valid timeString

This one (assuming that `year` is a 4 character string and `month` and `day` are 2 character strings) is:

```
cv.put("date", year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
```

For your reference: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Unfortunately im still getting this error.. And you forgot to put ; at the end" + Note + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

Comment: The `;` at the end is **completely useless**.